# get Yaw Pitch Roll values

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get the yaw pitch roll values between joint and world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381257/get-yaw-pitch-roll-values/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the command line: `rosrun tf tf_echo source_frame target_frame`

In Python:

```
import tf
listener = tf.TransformListener()
p_joint = geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped()
p_joint.header.frame_id = "your_joint"
p_joint_in_world = listener.transformPose("world", p_joint)
q = p_joint_in_world.pose.orientation  # Quaternion
rpy = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w)
```

In C++, I don't have boilerplate code on hand, but you could convert the `geometry_msg.msg.Quaternion` a [Tf::Quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html), convert it to a Matrix3x3 and call [getRPY](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html#a1be746de60c15a17ac1b52938d61f7c2).

This answer assumes that you meant "Roll Pitch Yaw", because this is the standard in robotics. If you really need the YPR Euler angles, use the [euler_from_quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/tf/html/python/transformations.html#tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion)  function's `axes` parameter in Python, or the [getEulerYPR](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html#a0dd7f86db3d1b3847f174291160efa7a) function in C++.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-06-28**:
its worked thank you